# Error al desplegar Web service Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, webservice

estoy en un proyecto de un web service y al intentar correr el web service me arroja el siguiente error, mi compañero de trabajo lo corrió de la misma manera y el no tuvo problema.

```
FALLO - Apliación desplegada en la ruta de contexto /proveedoresetiquetas, pero el contexto no pudo arrancar
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\MejoraProcesoDescargaEtiquetas\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1173: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

Me voy al archivo XML a revisar la linea que marca : 1173

y contiene lo siguiente

```
 <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="true"/>
```

Tengo todo el dia intentado correr el WS pero no puedo debido a este problema, alguien que le haya ocurrido o mismo podria ayudarme?

Comment: y revisaste el server log como te está indicando?

Comment: Si, aparece lo siguiente en el log

oct 23, 2020 8:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error in resourceStart()
oct 23, 2020 8:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error getConfigured
oct 23, 2020 8:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Falló en arranque del Contexto [/proveedoresetiquetas] debido a errores previos